# TelegramBot 400 Bad Request: media not found

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, memorystream

I try to send album by telegram bot.
Sometimes I get error `Telegram.Bot.Exceptions.ApiRequestException: Bad Request: media not found at Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient.MakeRequestAsync[TResponse](IRequest 1 request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`. InputMedia not is empty. Whats is wrong?

```
    var streams = new List<Stream>();
    try
    {       

        List<IAlbumInputMedia> inputMedia = new List<IAlbumInputMedia>();

        foreach (var image in images)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream(image.Data, false);
            var photo = new InputMedia(stream, image.Name);
            inputMedia.Add(new InputMediaPhoto(photo) {Caption = image.Name});
            streams.Add(stream);
        }

        var response = await _bot.SendMediaGroupAsync(inputMedia, chatId, cancellationToken: token);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which was caused by `image.Name` in your code. it should be only like someImage.png or someImage.jpg. You probably have "C:\SomeStuff\someImage.png" over there which is FULL Name intead of name, so Stream is good but name is wrong and the Api is confused